# Whats faster when using jquery selectors .classname or div.classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it faster to use

```
$(".classname").
```

or add the tag to look for as well

```
$("div.classname")
```

I think its the classname as i'm sure jquery will just loop through to get all classnames where the 2nd one will first get all the div tags and then loop through that subset to get the classnames. Thats what i think anyway.

Anyone know?

Comment: Definately `div.classname` because you already filtered it out with div

Comment: It is more about scoping rather than performance. The former selects all the elements of class `classname`, while the latter selects only `div`s with class `classname`. The lesser the scope, the better the performance.

Comment: do a test by your self....

Comment: The underlaying engine is still `JavaScript`. Which means that jQuery will use `document.querySelectorAll` on modern browsers. Selecting only `div`s from the DOM tree will be faster than selecting all elements with `.classname` in my opinion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery passes both of these selectors to the native DOM implementation, so jQuery doesn't matter. And then it mostly depends on the actual DOM structure and the browser engine you are using.

Comment: @31piy if i run this test https://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/2 its faster without the scope. so adding scope seems to giver worse performance. can you explain cause i thought your comment and logic was right. does the engine work from right to left? so does it get all classNames and then if you specify an element (div) it loops through to get those. thats the only way i can think of why it takes longer. thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always run your code on [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com) to check code sequence performance in different browsers.

About your questions. Chrome run shows that strict selector (tag + class name) is much slower than class selector only

[image]

Anyway you can rerun this code in different browsers to use different program flow based on browser type.

https://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/2